# Sprout Email - accessing custom fields

Tags: plugin-sproutemail

I'd like to set up a notification if an entry is saved in a the section 'memberNewsFeed'. The data that I would like to access is the entry title and url, and the user who made the change.

Can anybody advise of the syntax to input into rich text field that comes as standard with sprout email please?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the dynamic variables in your custom fields using single curly brace syntax:

- Title: `{title}`
- URL: `{url}`
- Author Name: `{author.fullName}`
- Author Email: `{author.email}`

There is a longer discussion on [Dynamic Values](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/email/docs/notifications/dynamic-values#using-dynamic-values-in-your-notification-entry-fields) in the docs.